# How to use and stabilize IdHttp for a large number of sites

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy, indy10, idhttp

I have about 30 unique sites which I login to and download a few files from each one of them. Sometimes I have about 50 sites, which the 20 extra are the same as previous ones but with different login credentials.

If I run the download process for any of them with all the other sites disabled, all of them work great.  But if I try to download them one after another, I usually get about 5-10 errors from 40 sites!

Exceptions that occur are usually `socket error`, `connection closed gracefully` or `unknown error occured`!

Right now, I create a class for each site, and in each class I create a `TIdHTTP` or `TIdFTP` object (very few are FTP and I don't have a problem with any of them). When the download from one class is finished, I destroy the class and destroy the `TIdHTTP`, and start the download process for the next class (or site), **so the downloads are not parallel**.  But I do create about 40 `TIdHTTP` and a few `TIdFTP` objects at the very beginning, and I start the download process one after another.

Is my approach correct?  Or should I use only one `TIdHTTP` object in all classes?  But if I have to do so, how can I refresh or reset it?  Sometimes I have to login to a single site multiple times with different credentials.

I should also mention that one approach I came up with that did help a little bit (maybe solved one or two errors!) was this:

```
// mMaxTryCount is 4 and mSleepInterval is 1000
for I := 1 to mMaxTryCount do
begin
  if not(isSuccess) then
  begin
    if (i = mMaxTryCount) then
    begin
      responseCode.Clear;
      idHttp.Post(URL, requestList, responseCode);
    end
    else
      try
        responseCode.Clear;
        idHttp.Post(URL, requestList, responseCode);
        isSuccess := true;
      except
        Sleep(mSleepInterval * (i + (i - 1)));
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a new `TIdHTTP` object in each class. Indy works just fine in that regard. But if you are having so many problems, you likely have issues in your download code, which you have not shown yet. Or maybe the target servers are throttling your attempts to access them. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) demonstrating what you are actually doing.  And why don't you want to do things in parallel? That would likely reduce the total time needed to process so many sites.

Comment: @RemyLebeau after doing a remote desktop to my client computer using team viewer, i tried to find the problem (or at least find a base to reproduce it !), and as i was analyzing i noticed that the posts that are beings sent (for about 10 of 40-50 sites), have "???" as value! and some had weird characters! and those "???" were unicode values! i tried typing in that language and the computer did support it! so the unicode font and ... were all installed, in the end i tried changing language region and it did the trick! it seems the posts are only send correctly if the "language for non unicode"

Comment: @RemyLebeau continuing on the previous commnect : programs" is set to persian (in my case), and the reason i did not use parallel is because i was afraid the program becomes more unstable ! because i read an article where someone said even after freeing netHttpClient(which i take it is the same as idHttp), the site might still keeps it alive for 240 second and its better to use one single client!,  anyway, i still sometimes get 2-3 error but with another try, it gets fixed, so any advice and tips on making the idHttp more stable are still welcome. thanks for your answers and comments.

Comment: @RemyLebeau just to clarify things, those 2-3 error only get fixed if i wait until the program is finished and i try downloading them one by one (they don't work in batch) so the main question is still valid.

Comment: the Unicode issue implies that your code is not handling Unicode data correctly. Indy 10 is Unicode aware, but you might still have to tell it which charset to use for encoding properly. And NetHttpClient is nothing like TIdHTTP. Using multiple clients in parallel works fine as long as you manage them correctly. But you still have not shown any of your download code yet, so nobody can help you "fix" it since we can't see if you are doing anything wrong with it.